# Android loading from file Error

Tags: java, android, serialization, buffer, ioexception

I am getting the occassional error message when I try to read a serialized object from a file. It works fine 9 times out of 10, but for some reason I get lots of these error message sin the catlog:

```
    06-01 23:57:50.824: ERROR/MemoryFile(16077): MemoryFile.finalize() called while ashmem 
    still open
```

and

```
    06-01 23:57:57.664: ERROR/MemoryFile(16077): java.io.IOException: munmap failed
```

The second message comes with no indication where the exception is caused. (Clearly when I'm loading the file, but I already have a try/catch around it.)

My loadfile method looks like this:

```
     public TGame loadSavedGame(){
    TGame g=null;
    InputStream instream = null;
    BufferedReader br=null;
    InputStreamReader inputreader=null;

    try {
         File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        instream = new
              FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/egyptica/serializationtest");
        // inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        // br= new BufferedReader(inputreader);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(instream);
         try {
            g= (TGame) ois.readObject();

            try {
                instream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return g;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            android.util.Log.e("DESERIALIZATION FAILED (CLASS NOT 
          FOUND):"+ex.getMessage(), "ex");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
     } catch (StreamCorruptedException ex) {
            android.util.Log.e("DESERIALIZATION FAILED (CORRUPT):"+ex.getMessage(), 
             "ex");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            android.util.Log.e("DESERIALIZATION FAILED (IO 
                      EXCEPTION):"+ex.getMessage(), "ex");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    }
```

One possibility I have thought of is using a BufferedReader to rea the file. However I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `finally` block after `try` and put there closing statements for your streams and also useful thing is to use:

```
FileInputStream.getFD().sync();
```

It makes sure that file really received your close/flush